# How to create a Mini Map in Android Google Maps API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I want to use a kind of "mini map" over my GoogleMap. The minimum requisites are create markers and change zoom dynamically (of both). Is there an easier way than create two GoogleMaps with two fragments?

I think using two GoogleMaps at the same time decreases the performance, I didn't try it yet.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/miniMap"
        android:name="com.example.presentation.views.MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bigMap"
        android:name="com.example.presentation.views.MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can tell you that two GoogleMaps cannot work together if they collapse with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Sample app of Google play service have provided 4 maps together them selves.
You can find it under Android-sdk:

> ~\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps\src\com\example\mapdemo\MultiMapDemoAtivity.java